# Local build of OpenTelemetry Collector Contrib

Tags: open-telemetry, open-telemetry-collector

I'm new to OpenTelemetry and trying out building locally for now. I'm following [the guide in the Local section here](https://opentelemetry.io/docs/collector/getting-started/#local).

Running the following works flawlessly:

```
git clone https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector.git
cd opentelemetry-collector
make install-tools
make otelcorecol
./bin/otelcorecol_* --config ./examples/local/otel-config.yaml
```

It works! Yay!

But I want to build the OpenTelemetry Collector Contrib instead of just the OpenTelemetry Collector. So I'm trying:

```
git clone https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib.git
cd opentelemetry-collector-contrib
make install-tools
make otelcorecol
```

...but here I get the following error: `make: *** No rule to make target 'otelcorecol'.  Stop.`

I want to build the Contrib-version because I want to use the file-exporter, which is not included in the non-Contrib-version, as far as I know.

I'm on macOS.

Any help would be very much appreciated! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The corresponding `make` target for **opentelemetry-collector-contrib** is `otelcontribcol`, so you'll have to run this instead:

```
make otelcontribcol
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to build the official OpenTelemetry Collector Contrib distribution, please use this repository:

https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-releases

From the root of the git checkout of the repository, enter:

```
$> make build
```

The cmd/otelcontribcol executable in opentelemetry-collector-contrib is used for integration testing.

Comment: I tried this but can't make it run in Ternimal! 

When using `make build` on https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-releases I try to start it with:

`~/bin/ocb --config /path/to/otel-config.yaml`

...but I get the following error:

`Error: invalid configuration: module "": invalid gomod specification for module; module "": invalid gomod specification for module; module "": invalid gomod specification for module; module "": invalid gomod specification for module`

Any help would be very valued! 

Comment: You should run `cmd/otelcontribcol`, not `ocb`. Try `cmd/otelcontribcol --config /path/to/otel-config.yaml`